# How to enable the building of the "Hotspot & tethering" settings app in AOSP?

Tags: android-source, android-10.0, hotspot, tethering

I have an AOSP build for my Android 10 device.

The 'Network & internet' UI is missing the 'Hotspot & tethering' settings app.  (Wifi is working, but only as an upstream interface.)

Which file in AOSP controls whether the 'Hotspot & tethering' settings app is included in the build?

Comment: Do you have the Settings app but only missing the 'Hotspot and tethering' page? If so, that's probably not compile time but more of a runtime hiding of the page. You can see more in the code here:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/TetherSettings.java;l=148?q=if%5C%20%5C(isUiRestricted%5C(%5C)%5C)%20f:tethersettings%5C.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, that's right.  I can force the 'Hotspot & tethering' UI to start from 'adb shell', but it's empty, apart from an information line.  Could this be carrier or SIM related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to add the `<item>` line, below, to `./frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml`.

```
<!-- List of regexpressions describing the interface (if any) that represent tetherable
     Wifi interfaces.  If the device doesn't want to support tethering over Wifi this
     should be empty.  An example would be "softap.*" -->
<string-array translatable="false" name="config_tether_wifi_regexs">
    <item>"softap.*"</item>
</string-array>
```